# jquery validation plugin - default values and validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form input such as below for an email address.  In this particular scenario I want to allow the user to change their current email address if they wish.  I am listing their current email as the default value when the form loads. onblur if the value='' then I reset the value to the default again.

It works as expected with one exception.  If you clear the value so there is no email... required validation kicks in (in this case the message 'Email is required.') as expected and when you onblur the default value is replaced, BUT the error message still stays until you onfocus and onblur again.

**html example input**

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label><b>Email</b></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>'}"/>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

**validation**

```
$('#account-info-form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Email is required.",
            email: "Enter a valid email address."
        }
    },

    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
        $(element)
            .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
    },

    success: function (label) {
        label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        label.remove();
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.closest('.input-group'));
    }

});
```

EDIT :

To make this clearer.  An input is given a default value="something".  If the user were to erase the value and out of focus for that input the default value is returned to the input.  This is working as shown above, but the error field still shows.  I can only assume this is because it is validated before my onblue replaces the default value.  To support this, you can focus back on the value then out again and the error disappears.

I want to accomplish something like :

```
if (inputvalue == ''){
   inputvalue = defaultvalue; // if it was supplied in html (either way it would not matter as ifit wasn't it would just stay blank)
   now perform validation so the field is not tagged as an error since the original valid value was replaced to due being blank
}
```

**Solution : (credit to Sparky)**

Using jquery I can accomplish the default value always being replaced on blank input (user deletes the default value on form load).  They can also change the value of course and normal validation rules will apply such as email, required, etc.

I modified the solution slightly to make it more universal for use on multiple inputs.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" data-default="true" value="this is the default value" />
```

Note the addition of the data-default="true". Then in jquery outside of your validate() handler...

```
$('input[data-default="true"]').on('blur', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ) { // values is blank from being deleted by user
        $(this).val( this.defaultValue ); // set it back to default
        $(this).valid(); // trigger validation after setting default back (remove incorrect errors assuming default value is valid)
    }
});
```

Comment: You merely described the current behavior.  You have not explained what you want it to do.  The jQuery Validation plugin's validation routine, by default, is triggered by several events... on the field blur, on every keystroke within the field, and by clicking the submit.  To answer your question, we have to know exactly what event you expect to trigger validation, and then we can decide which callback function to modify.

Comment: I explained it perfectly clear if you look.  Please read the second paragraph.  The error message should not stay on for the input after focus because I am filling blank with the original default value when this happens.  If there was a way to add my default value on blank BEFORE validation I believe that would solve the problem.

Comment: [I'm very experienced with this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/topusers) and wouldn't have asked you for a better explanation if it was _"perfectly"_ clear. So please tone down the attitude a bit... nobody asks for clarification in order to annoy you. After all, you're getting free help as long as you take the time to be clear & concise about what you want to do.

Comment: No attitude over here...chalk it up to one of the faults of the web... how someone reads your words it not always how you say them.  I will take a look at this now.  As always, thanks in advance for the assistance and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid), which will trigger an immediate validation test of the field.  Attach to the whole form or a field...

```
$('#myField').valid();
```

Or within your `blur` event handler (line breaks for readability)...

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email"
    value="<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>"
    onblur="if(this.value == '') {
        this.value='<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>';
        this.valid();  // <-- trigger validation test of this field
    }"
/>
```

---

Or better yet, use jQuery to eliminate the inline JavaScript...

```
$('input[name="email"]').on('blur', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).val( "<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>" );
        $(this).valid(); // <-- trigger validation test of this field
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, with inline js I am having the same issues I originally was.  Default value is set as a valid email.  My rules are required and email for this input.  On initial page load if I delete the email address and focus out it replaces the value with no errors.  If I trigger the email rule then delete the full value and go out it triggers the required rule... replaces the value and the error stays unless I return focus and go back out where it validates and removes the error.

Comment: The jquery method will just not work.  While it appears to perform the right tasks the default is replaced with the literal php statement and not its actual value representation.  This then triggers the invalid email error because "<?php echo $_SESSION['account']['account_email']; ?>" is not a valid email. I need something like element.defaultValue outside of the validate() handler which represents that initial value to correctly set it.

Comment: $(this).val( this.defaultValue ); solves the issue using the jquery method.  Thank you for the assistance!